# Getting the related string data while groupingby sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like:

```
id   name1   name2   name3
1    yok     null     null
1    null    yok      null
1    null    null     yok
```

What I want as output is:

```
id   name1   name2   name3
1    yok     yok     yok
```

What I tried is:

```
select id, name1, name2, name3
from trial
group by id
```

Table creation script is  below:

```
Create table trial (id int, name1 varchar(10),name2 varchar(10),name3 varchar(10))
insert into trial values (1,'yok',null,null)
insert into trial values (1,null,'yok',null)
insert into trial values (1,null,null,'yok')
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Keep group by, do MAX(name1) etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try statement like below

```
Select 
  id,
  max(name1) name1,
  max(name2) name2,
  max(name3) name3
from trial
group by id
```

**[Sql demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c091/1)**